# create generic method for abstract inherited class without interface

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm not sure if this question has come up before but I certainly haven't found an answer to it yet so here I am asking the community.

I have a third party library that has an abstract class (lets say A) which implements IXinterface

```
public abstract class A : IXinterface{

}
```

This class is then derived by a number of child classes, Each one of these classes have properties such Product

```
public class B : A {
    public Product Product {get; set; }
}

public class C : A {
    public Product Product {get; set; }
}
```

my issue is this.

I would like to create a generic method that such as this:

```
public List<PriceModel> GetPriceModelList(List<PriceModel> priceModelList, List<T> resultsList) where T : class
{
    priceModelList.AddRange(from result in resultsList
                            from item in result.Product.Price
                            select new PriceModel 
                            {
                                Price = item.price
                            });
    return priceModelList;
}
```

I want to be able to do something like this

```
GetPriceModelList(new List<PriceModel>(), new List<B>());
GetPriceModelList(new List<PriceModel>(), new List<C>());
```

OR

change method signiture to accept T

```
GetPriceModelList<B>(new List<PriceModel>(), resultsList);
GetPriceModelList<C>(new List<PriceModel>(), resultsList);
```

obviously because I do not have a common concrete class or interface I can not explicitly state the type T and the abstract class does not have accessor methods to the derived classes properties. Therefore when result is fetched from the List of type T Product is not available.

Is there a way around this issue

Comment: introduce an interface for property `Product` and use it in your `where`?

Comment: Are B and C under your control, or are they *also* part of the third-party library?

Comment: also third party. I have updated the question to clear up any misunderstandings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cut out the intermediary, and directly operate on sequences of products.

```
public List<PriceModel> GetPriceModelList(
    List<PriceModel> priceModelList, 
    IEnumerable<Product> products) 
{
    priceModelList.AddRange(from result in products
                            from item in result.Product.Price
                            select new PriceModel 
                            {
                                Price = item.price
                            });
    return priceModelList;
}
```

That would mean you'd have to provide the mechanism for getting each product at the call site.

```
GetPriceModelList(new List<PriceModel>(), new List<B>().Select(b => b.Product));
GetPriceModelList(new List<PriceModel>(), new List<C>().Select(c => c.Product));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain the `from item in result.Product.Price` line?

For me it looks like you just want:

```
priceModelList.AddRange(from result in resultsList
                        select new PriceModel 
                        {
                            Price = result.Product.Price
                        });
```

To do that, you can just replace it with:

```
priceModelList.AddRange(from result in new List<dynamic>(resultsList)
                        select new PriceModel
                        {
                            Price = result.Product.Price
                        });
```

Then you can even call it in this way:

```
GetPriceModelList(new List<PriceModel>(), 
                  new List<A>
                  {
                      new B { Product = new Product() }, 
                      new C { Product = new Product() }
                  });
```

But it is also a good idea to guard yourself by checking if T is actually of type B or C.